# Knockout.js: Filter array on subscribe

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an `observableArray` that in its subscribe callback I need to filter the new array passed.

For example:

```
myArray.subscribe(function(elements) {
 ko.utils.arrayFilter(elements, function(element) {
  return element.x > 10
 })
})
```

This, of course, doesn't work since `arrayFilter` nor the native `filter()` method doesn't change the original array. The problem is that i can't do this:

```
myArray.subscribe(function(elements) {
 var newArray = ko.utils.arrayFilter(elements, function(element) {
  return element.x > 10
 })

myArray(newArray)
})
```

because this would be an infinite loop. How would I filter the array inside the subscription function?

Comment: Why is it necessary to filter the original array? Can't you just use a computed which does the filtering?

Comment: Or if there's a bunch of stuff that relies on this one directly so you can't switch to a computed, you could make it so it doesn't call `myArray(newArray)` if nothing was actually filtered out - would only do one recursive call then.

Comment: Hmm seems that I can do all my operations inside the subscribe function and create an computed to only filter the array. Thanks nemesv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is the one suggested by nemesv: Don't alter the array itself, but instead create a new computed observable that encapsulates the filter behavior.

```
var filteredArray = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(myArray(), function(element) {
        return element.x > 10;
    });
});
```

The simplest solution, if you're feeling lazy, would be to replace

```
myArray(newArray)
```

with

```
if (newArray.length !== elements.length) {
    myArray(newArray);
}
```

as suggested in the comment by James Thorpe. The flaw here is that every subscriber might run twice, including the filter operation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem implies that you really want to encapsulate your data and not to expose it directly over the view-model.

Try something like this:

```
var arr = ko.observableArray();

this.AddItem = function(element) {
    if (element.x > 10)
        arr.push(element);
};

this.GetItems = function() {
    return arr();
};
```